# Is there an HTTP response code for a proxy to make browser directly connect to target?

Tags: http, http-proxy

I want to set up a custom proxy that proxies connections to some destinations (inside a network) but not other destinations (in the global internet). Is there any HTTP response the proxy server can send to make the browser connect directly to the requested destination?

For example, I request redirection to Google to my proxy server. The proxy server decides not to proxy, so I get this HTTP response, and my browser connects directly to Google.

Answer (score 0):

You could send a redirect http response code like `302` to redirect the client directly to the website. See: https://moz.com/learn/seo/redirection